# Simple write to Dexie without knowing the schema

Tags: dexie

Is it possible to write an entire object to Dexie without knowing the schema?
I just want to do this:

```
var db = new Dexie(gameDataLocalStorageName);
                db.version(1).stores({
                    myData: "gameData"
                });
                db.myData.put(gameData);
                console.log(db.myData.get('gameData'));
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection: DataError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value.
 DataError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you've specified the schema to use inbound key "gameData", i.e. require each object to have the property "gameData" as its primary key.

If you don't need to have the primary key within the objects, you can declare the schema as `{myData: ""}` instead of `{myData: "gameData"}`. By doing so, you will need to provide the primary key separate from the object in calls to `db.myData.put()`.

See docs for [inbound vs non-inbound keys](https://dexie.org/docs/inbound) and [detailed schema syntax](https://dexie.org/docs/Version/Version.stores()#detailed-schema-syntax)

```ts
var db = new Dexie(gameDataLocalStorageName);
db.version(1).stores({
  myData: ""
});
Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
  await db.myData.put(gameData, 'gameData'); // 'gameData' is key.
  console.log(await db.myData.get('gameData'));
}).catch(console.error);
```

Since we're changing the primary key here, you will need to delete the database in devtools before this would work.